# Javascript function not getting all values first time

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to let the user upload a list of items to filter a search results table by. The problem is that not all rows that don't have values in the filter list are removed the first time, so to get the program to do what I want I need to run it multiple times.

The attached code works, but I want to remove the 'badWorkAround()' function

```
<div align="center">
<script>
  function readList() {
  var origText = document.getElementById("CusipTextArea").value;
  var filterList = origText.split("\n");
  var table = document.getElementById("resultsTable");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 
  for(i = 1; i < rows.length; i++)  #first row has the column names so I start at i=1
 { 
   var Found = '0'
   for(j = 0; j < filterList.length; j++)
    {   
        if (rows[i].innerHTML.indexOf(filterList[j]) > 0){
        Found = '1'
        break;
            } 
        } 
    if (Found != '1'){rows[i].remove();}    
     } 
  }
  function badWorkAround(){
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
        readList();
  }
</script>
<textarea id=TextArea>Paste in a list to filter by. One per line please.</textarea><BR>
<button type="button" onclick="return badWorkAround();">Filter by List</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `cusipList` defined?

Comment: Sorry, cusipList was suppose to be filterList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NodeLists (like you get with getElementsByTagName) are “live”, meaning they reflect the current state of the DOM *at any time*.

You are looping over the TR nodes, and then removing some of them while doing so. Lets say you are at index 1 in your loop (second loop iteration), and remove that node – all following nodes “slide up” one position, so that what formerly was the node with the index 2 has now index 1, and what was 3 is now 2, etc. But since you are also increasing your loop counter `i` by one each loop, in your next iteration you access the node that is *now* the one at index 2 (formerly 3) – and the node that was at position 2 *before* is not even processed any more.

Easiest solution for this problem: Loop over the nodes **backwards**, from `rows.length - 1` to `0` (and *decrease* your loop counter variable then, obviously). Because if you remove a node at the *end* of the list, that does not affect the position of any nodes *before* it.

Comment: Ah! Silly mistake. Thank you very much. Worked beautifully