# Elegant way around HTMLCollections updating dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom, htmlcollection

Today, I discovered something in Javascript that looked like "strange behavior" to me. Let's assume the following minimal example:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var div   = document.getElementById('test');
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName('span');
div.removeChild(spans[0]);
div.removeChild(spans[1]);
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SkYJg/)

Now, when running the script, I get an error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.

Looking closer, it turned out that `spans[1]` is null **after the first one was removed**. And indeed, the following code

```
var div   = document.getElementById('test');
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName('span');
console.log(spans.length);
div.removeChild(spans[0]);
console.log(spans.length);
div.removeChild(spans[1]);
```

yields `2`at the first log operation, but `1` the second time.

Now, it's pretty clear what happens here: after the first ?span? was removed from DOM, it's not part fo that `HTMLCollection` stored inside `spans` anymore either.

I always was under the impression, that the `HTMLCollection`-Object holds references to all objects that it contains. I didn't modify the collection anywhere after creating it. So I thought (but it was wrong, obviously) that the collection would behave like an array: references stay there until I delete/modify them manually.

I looked into the [specification at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). And, indeed, richt at the top it says: `HTMLCollections in the HTML DOM are live; they are automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.`

The only way I could think of to prevent this is to loop over the collectino before doing anything with it, copying all references to an array, and use the array to access them afterwards. But that just looks so horribly bulky to me... is there a nicer solution? Like some way to make the collection static or to copy it without looping?

(in the minimal example I could just remove `spans[0]` twice, of course, but it isn't that simple in reality).

[Edit]: After seeing @Teemu's answer, I repeat: it's NOT that simple in my real code (that one is just too complex to show it here completely). I assure you, I really need random access to all elements that were inside that Collection, deleted or not.

Comment: If this is just about removing nodes, then the easiest way is to [loop through the NodeList in reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105426/javascript-function-not-getting-all-values-first-time/18105542#18105542).

Comment: It's not - see edit. SHould have mad that more clear.

Comment: Or you could remove `1` then `0`. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are just trying to convert the `nodeList` to a static array and can't use `querySelectAll` then you can just `Array.prototype.slice.call(spans)` and then it is no longer `live`

Comment: The latter would loop again - but I guess `querySelectorAll` is fine, see Teemu's answer.

Comment: What do you mean it would loop again? http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/SkYJg/1/

Comment: @Xotic750 WHen the engine is creating that shallow-copy of a non-array (but array-like, that is "implementing random access using square brackets") object, it will loop over all properties, the same way you could do manually (maybe less performance-.costly, since it's done internally without any JIT compiling). It would work, but it's not any better than looping manually I'd say. I prefer to get a static collection directtly (as `querySelectorAll` gives me)

Comment: Sure, `slice` will loop internally but what do you think that `querySelectorAll` does internally?

Comment: @Xotic SUre, it does loop, too, through all child elements. The difference is: `querySelectorAll` loops ONCE. The other way (using `getELementsByTagName` + `Array.prototype.slice`) loops TWICE. I cannot avoid looping once internally - but I can avoid the second one.

Comment: I think you are worrying unnecessarily. [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/21835282)

Comment: Yeah, no, I know it'S not a big deal performance wise. This was purely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A back-gate would be to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead of `getElementsByTagName()`, it returns a non-live [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: I can only use zero index if I really wanted to delete the first two. But I don't want to, it's just the minimal example. I really DO need random-access to all elements that were in the list, removed or not.

Comment: As for 'querySelectorAll': performance wise, it's a little slower - but I don't really mind. WHat bothers me more is that line from the specification: `In some cases, the NodeList is a live collection. This means that changes in the DOM are reflected in the collection.` Do you know any details on WHEN this is the case? The specification isn't really clear on this...

Comment: I was typing when you answer, I was thinking about this kind of way.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector clearly says, _“The NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll() method MUST be static.”_

Comment: @JohannesH. I haven't crushed that. Where can I find your citation?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, that'S all I need I guess ;)

Comment: @Teemu At the MDN dpocumentation of `NodeList` (the link you posted), first paragraph after `Description`.

Comment: @JohannesH. How I didn't notice it... I'd recall the behavior of `getElementsByClassName()` and other "getters" changed for a while ago, earlier they returned a NodeList, but recently the return value has been a HTMLCollection. This change is not affecting `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Accepted this answer, as it seems to work (fiddle to test it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/P6KJP/)

Comment: @Teemu LAst time I used it `getELementsByTagName` returned something static, too, as far as I remember - that'S why I was so surprised about that dynamic behaviour now. I wish there was some boolean argument or whatever to get a static collection instead...

Comment: That has to be a some while ago ; ). Anyway, better test also with older IEs, just in case, if you're going to support them ofcourse. And thanks @CBroe for the link to specs.

Comment: I don't have to, it's a private project, only supposed to run inside current versions of Firefox. BUt I'll check anyway, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score -1):

You're not using a "reference" when trying to remove the tag, just pointing the first or the second element of a collection. To use reference, you should create tags with ID and than point it by ID. The key of an Array is a third part, that's why it will be updated.

On the other hand, is a fact that JavaScript is objected-oriented sometimes, and other times it is just a script.

Comment: Javascript is fully Object oriented, and fully functional. But that doesn't matter at all ;) Behaviour is well-defined and documented. ANd yes, I **do** use references ("reference" as "pointer to an object"), the only alternative would be copies of those DOM notes, and that doesn't make sense at all (I could then modify anything inside the collectin without it affecting the DOM). Any programming language can only use copies or references to give you access to objects...

Comment: JavaScript support object oriented, is not fully at all, not as AS3. I said the key of an Array isn't a reference.

Comment: Contents of the HTMLCollection are references to the HTMLElement objects though - and that's what I was referring too. And there is nothing inside Javascript (besides primitive types) that's not represented by an OPbject - so if it doesn't count as OO, neither does Java or C# (as both have non-objects such as primitive types).

Comment: JavaScript is a prototype-based programming, not mentioned as a OO language. Take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: Terms, terms and terms again ;) `Prototype-based programming is a style of object-oriented programming` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) - but I guess we can stop arguing here, it's not taking us anywhere ^^

Comment: Never mind, I know it's out of the subject of the post. But as you're thinking in a conceptual way, you might consider the limits of JavaScript in OO style, though. I broke my face trying to port some classes from another languages... hope you succeed where I failed!