# js: for loop on all div in document to add a new div inside each of them ― the for loop include the newly added div

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have an html with many block like this :

```
 <div>
    <atitle>Title A</atitle>
    some content (ex: several pre blocks)
</div>
```

I would like to use a `js` script to transform each of these block into this:

```
<div class="divtitle">
    <button onclick="toggle('titlea')">Title A</button>
    <div id="titlea" class="codebox">some content</div>
</div>
```

This is the script I came up with

```
<script>
        // get all existing div in document
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        console.log(elements)
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var adiv = elements[i];

            // get title innerText  and remove title node (it will be re-added later)
            var atitle_node= adiv.getElementsByTagName("atitle")[0];
            var atitle_innerHtml = atitle_node.innerHTML;
            adiv.removeChild(atitle_node);
            var content = adiv.innerText;

            // parse title innerText to remove non alpha character so it can be used as id 
            var atitle_removenonalphachar = atitle_innerHtml.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '')
            var attitle_lower= atitle_removenonalphachar.toLowerCase();

            // modify adiv content
            adiv.innerHTML="<button onclick=\"toggle('"  + attitle_lower  + "')\">"+ atitle_innerHtml + "</button><div id=\""  + attitle_lower + "\" class=\"codebox\">" + content + "</div>";
            adiv.setAttribute("class", "divtitle");
        }
</script>
```

This script is working for the first div, but not the following ones. 
This is really strange too me as I am new to `js` but I think it's because I add a div inside the div (cf adiv.innerHTML) and thus the for loop doesn't proceed to the next div I want, but to the div inside the first div.

I can see it by opening the `HTMLCollection(3) [div, div, div]` in the console. Even thought the "title" indicated 3 div, when I open it, I see the 3 divs I expected plus the newly added on.

So my question is : How can I prevent the for loop to include the div I am adding dynamically?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vnwtpy47/) is a full script. You can see the final "effect" I want on the first div "Title A".

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve and what isn't working - but from what you say, it's looping over all the divs because that's what you're telling it to do: `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div")` makes `elements` hold all divs on the page. If you only want to include certain divs but not others, you have to select them some other way - easiest would be to add a class to the divs you're interested in and then use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @RobinZigmond, thanks for your help. I want to include all the divs that are "hard coded" in my script. But I don't want to include the divs that I generate in my for loop when I am modifying the innerHtml of my divs. Step 1 of for loop works as expected but step 2 does proceed to the 2 "hard coded div" but to the first div created dynamically.

Comment: What confuse me, is that some how the variable `elements` is modified by the for loop even though I have created it before the for loop.

Comment: that's because the collection assigned to `elements` is "[live](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)" - *An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.*

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that! Thanks for that! Everything makes sense now! Is there a way to "un-live" the collection (ex: by making a copy), because I don't want to overcharge my hard coded file with class name on every of my div.

Comment: btw there is no such html element as `<atitle>` (there is a `<title>` but that means something totally different and shouldn't be used in the body). You should just use an appropriate heading tag (`<h1>`, ..., `<h6>`), and give it a class if you need to distinguish it further.

Comment: Ok, I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835282/elegant-way-around-htmlcollections-updating-dynamically

Comment: You're right for `atitle`, but I use it as a custom tag.

Comment: Convert the HTMLCollection to an array will "un-live" it ``Array.prototype.slice.call( htmlCollection )``

Comment: @CodySwann, please add this as in an answer, so I can up vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CodySwann proposed in the comment, I simply had to add this line:

```
var elements_fixed = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements_live)
```

just below this one:

```
var elements_live= document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

And then run the `for`loop on `elements_fixed` like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements_fixed.length; i++) {
...
...
}
```

---

If you need to keep the elements collections "live", you can instead use [custom html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21175701/3154274) for the children block.

So instead of modifying the `adiv.innerHTML` with this:

```
<div id=\""  + attitle_lower + "\" class=\"codebox\">" + content + "</div>"
```

Modify it with something like `div-toggle`:

```
<div-toggle id=\""  + attitle_lower + "\" class=\"codebox\">" + content + "</div-toggle>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this code. please take a look.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   ModifyStructure();
});
function ModifyStructure(){
    var selector=$("div");
    selector.each(function(i,o){
         var currentObj=$(this);
         var innerHTML=currentObj[0].innerHTML;
         var titleText=currentObj[0].children[0].innerText;
         var remainingtext=innerHTML.substr(innerHTML.lastIndexOf(">")+1,innerHTML.length).trim();
         var btn=$("<button/>",{text:titleText});
         btn.on('click',function(){
             toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase())
           })
         currentObj.html('')
         currentObj.append(btn);
         var divtext=remainingtext.substr(0,remainingtext.indexOf("(")-1)
         var div=$("<div/>",{id:titleText.toLowerCase(),class:"codebox",text:divtext});
         currentObj.append(div);
   })
}
function toggle(current){
 console.log(current);
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```